# Square summable solutions of second order difference equations

Tags: recurrence-relations, spectral-theory

There should be a standard argument for the following claim: If the system of equations of the form
$$a_{n-1}u_{n-1}+(b_{n}-z)u_{n}+a_{n}u_{n+1}=0, \quad n\in\mathbb{Z},$$
where $a_{n}\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ and $b_{n}\in\mathbb{C}$, has two linearly independent square summable solutions (i.e., in $\ell^{2}(\mathbb{Z})$) **for one** $z\in\mathbb{C}$, then the same holds true **for all** $z\in\mathbb{C}$.

Is there a reasonably simple (or more or less elementary) proof?

Comment: Perhaps you're aware of this context, but: If $u_n$ is understood as a function of $z$, then by [Favard's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favard's_theorem) $\{u_n(z)\}$ is a sequence of orthogonal polynomials on the real line (modulo some assumptions on $\{a_n,b_n\}$). There's a ton of literature on such orthogonal polynomials, but one very good ref is Barry Simon's "Szegő's Theorem and Its Descendants," esp. the discussion of the above as a Jacobi operator (self-adjoint bounded operator on $\ell^2$).

Comment: I guess you mean "<b>for all</b> $z\in\mathbb{C}$".

Comment: To Keith McClary: You are right. That is a typo, I correct it.